# Vuex Getter Hook with Params

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I defined a vuex getter function with parameter like this:

```
    const getters = {
        
        getProjectById: (state) => (id) => {
            return state.projects.find(project => project.id === id)
        }
}
```

Now, i want to use this getter in my component, but i couldn't find a way to pass the parameter to the getter.

Here is my getter hook computed property:

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["currentUserPhoto","getProjectById"])
},
```

Is it possible to pass Id parameter which is come from router, to "getProjectId" getter? If is possible, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another computed property called `projectById` which takes the route param as parameter and returns the project :

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["currentUserPhoto","getProjectById"]),
   projectById(){
         return this.getProjectById(this.$route.params.id)
  }

},
```